# How to stop links in comments taking up the entire character allowance

Tags: discussion

I don't know if this has happened to you, but I find it excruciatingly annoying when, in a relatively short comment, a link I've included takes up a hundred or even two hundred characters, thereby rendering my comment too long and forcing me to chop it up and continue in another box.

Here's an example. Suppose I look up on Google Books the phrase "you met's" because I want to find and share examples of a [noun + relative clause] being used as a Determiner, as in:

- That woman you met's husband

This would give me the URL:

- https://www.google.com/search?q=%22you+met%27s%22&source=lnms&tbm=bks&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwiWzvvL46f2AhUQi1wKHRFaBzgQ_AUoAXoECAEQCw&biw=1366&bih=615&dpr=1

... which could take up a huge chink of the character allowance.

Is there any way around this annoying problem?

Comment: Could you give an example? There are definitely short forms of StackExchange links available (particularly for links on the same site).

Comment: @AndrewLeach Done,

Answer (score 12):

For the Google link in the question, simply strip off everything not relevant.

`q="you met's"` is relevant and needs to stay, but the `&` after that and everything else is irrelevant. You can even use just the domain name: for these links, `www.` isn't needed. Note that some characters are expanded to their encoded form when displayed, but I typed `https://google.com/search?q="you met's"` for the URL, and that's what was displayed in the answer preview.

https://google.com/search?q=%22you%20met%27s%22

If you want to get results in books, include the `&tbm=bks` part. `https://www.google.com/search?q="you met's"&tbm=bks`. There will be a similar specification for other result sets.

https://www.google.com/search?q=%22you+met%27s%22&tbm=bks

For links to ELU questions, you can omit almost everything except the post number for a post on the same site: this question is number 15230 on Meta.ELU, so you can enter a link with just a relative URL: [link](/q/15230) which is coded as `[link](/q/15230)` and is a lot shorter than `https://english.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/15230/how-to-stop-links-in-comments-taking-up-the-entire-character-allowance`

Links can always be examined in the source code of a post if you're unsure of their destination, although browsers do a good job of interpreting them these days and displaying some sort of status text. The days of using JavaScript to alter the status bar when hovering over a link are over; and Stack Exchange doesn't allow scripting anyway.

It's this facility which explains why link shorteners are frowned upon — a link to a tinyurl URL shows no information about where that link will *actually* end up. Here's one which I will say will go to OED. It doesn't, but it's safe to click on: [link to OED](https://tinyurl.com/yae6wd2m) `https://tinyurl.com/yae6wd2m` [Check the edit history if you want to see whether the link is still what I originally started out with: it could have been altered and there's no way of knowing the destination.]

Link shorteners are improved when there's a preview possible: [this is the same link](https://preview.tinyurl.com/yae6wd2m) but to a preview page `https://preview.tinyurl.com/yae6wd2m` which shows you exactly where it's going. With tinyurl it's possible for users to set a cookie so that they always get the preview, but that's an **end-user** setting. When you're constructing a link, using the `preview` version of the URL forces that behaviour.

Comment: Great! Thanks. However, the first link you gave doesn't take me to examples in published books. How would I solve that?

Comment: You need to put in what is necessary. That appears to be set with the `&tbm=bks` part. `https://www.google.com/search?q="you met's"&tbm=bks` https://www.google.com/search?q=%22you+met%27s%22&tbm=bks

Comment: To get the 'preview' version can you always simply add 'preview.' between the slashes and 'tinyurl'?

Comment: It appears to be. The old version of their bookmarklet created a preview link as well as the "direct" link, but that seems to have changed. However, the preview link I created here works, so I guess that's the way to do it. I would still counsel that link shorteners are the last resort though: shorten links with the right domain name wherever that's possible (and since tinyurl needs `preview` to be added, some editing is needed anyway). **And** adding links to comments suggests that you are answering in comments, which is *definitely* frowned upon.

Comment: I won't comment on answering in comments in general. However, I can confidently say that the links I've used have not been part of such frowned-upon activities.

Comment: @AndrewLeach Thank you for these suggestions, they're very helpful. However, I think that it is still tough to shorten some URLs. For example, in Google Books ngrams, the URL might include "year_start=1800", "year_end=2019", "corpus=26", "case_insensitive=true", etc. I assume that if you didn't want default values, then you couldn't eliminate those, so the URL could still be very long.

Answer (score 2):

Funny you should ask. I've recently stumbled across a really useful solution to this problem. More specifically, I was shown how to do it to reduce a four-line URL that I had to include in a document. Most of you are probably intimately familiar with it, so this is for those of you who might find it useful who aren't.

This does involve a particular website, but it's so useful and the website so well-known that I doubt this will be taken as an advertisement here.

The solution is to go to:

- [tinyurl.com](https://tinyurl.com/app)

Stick your diplodocus-length URL in the box there and let it generate a nice squat wombat-length one for you. Then use that for your link in your comment box.

For the long URL link in your question, this would give you a wieldy replacement of something like

- https://tinyurl.com/377u3fft

Bingo.

Comment: Link shorteners are frowned upon. They could link to anything.

Comment: @AndrewLeach Fair enough, but I don't understand that at all. Once it's been formatted as a link, any link could link to anything!

Comment: @AndrewLeachAnd just to support the point, I've used lots of them over the past few weeks and no-one's ever looked inside the comment at the link, otherwise, presumably they'd have pulled me up on it! How often do you check the URL's inside a link?

Comment: Always; well, I can generally rely on the browser to do it for me.